# Call firebase getvalue oncreate

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
mRefQ.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String txt = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        showtext.setText(txt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

as it stands i can only access the value when the data is changed but i want to access it whenever i want(namely oncreate).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firebase documentation for listening to value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events):

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Data only once by following [this steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#read_data_once).

As @Frank mentioned having a listener will give you access when attached and every time it changes.

Bear in mind that **all of this happens asynchronously** on a separate thread, therefore in order to ensure the value is available on onCreate you may have to do the orchestration yourself and hold the main thread until the values is ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it turns out it does call it when created, i just had to wait for the firebase to load up on the app

Answer (score 0):

It is not triggerred once in onCreate() method. Without removeEventListener, addValueEventListener will never stop if you listen it in OnCreate() Method. Count is increasing and never stops and load was up to 85% when I run it and so I had to close my internet and uninstall it. But i[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U3XS.png)t has just been solved. Here's my code if you wanna check it.

Variables are declared global...

```
private DatabaseReference main;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
```

In onCreate() Method.....

```
valueEventListener = main.addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           boolean countExists = false;
           int count = 1; //starts from 1 when data is uploaded for the first time
           for (DataSnapshot out: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               if (out.getKey().equals("count")) {
                   String temp = out.getValue(String.class);
                   countExists = true;
                   try {
                       count = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                   }
                   catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                       count = 1;
                   }
                   break;
               }
           }

           if (!countExists) {
               main.child("count").setValue(String.valueOf(count));
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Count Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               upload.setClickable(true);
           }
           else {
               main.child("count").setValue(String.valueOf(++count));
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Count Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               upload.setClickable(true);
           }
           main.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Make sure you add removeEventListener when you call it in onCreate() method or it will never stops. It is not a problem if you don't call removeEventListener in onStart() method.

This is not your question but...

If you wanna use firebase for likely free, you can't let all users to download your data without necessary or your bandwidth may become full within a day. So, I count the data and just download that child's value and compare the result and make update. So it can reduce your bandwidth when you call addValueListener.